# How do you enable YouTube when you click on IMG?

Tags: jquery, css, events, youtube

I am developing an website where my client wants to be able to play an youtube video when he clicks an image and when the video finishes, the video disappears and the same image reappears again.

```css
.boxyt {
  position: relative;
}

.boxyt .imgyt {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0
}

.imgyt:before {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.59;
  background-color: #f1d2cd;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 0;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="m-auto boxyt">
  <div class="imgyt"><img src=".../images/youtube.png"></div>
  <?php the_field('youtube'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I have searched many solutions, but none of them works. :(

Comment: So **show us what you tried**, don't just drop a problem on SO, you have to demonstrate what it is you tried.

Comment: For the first part, you could just replace the image with a simple iframe on click via JavaScript. For the second part, to show the image again when the video is finished playing, you will need to use the YT Player API, https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

HTML

```
<div class="ytvideo" data-video="7ixLP6mUqnw" style="width:560px; height:315px; background-image:url(https://img.youtube.com/vi/7ixLP6mUqnw/hqdefault.jpg)">
```

Have a meaningful description of the video here

jQuery

```
 // VIDEO 2
$('.ytvideo[data-video]').one('click', function() {

var $this = $(this);
var width = $this.attr("width");
var height = $this.attr("height");

$this.html('<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + $this.data("video") + '?autoplay=1"></iframe>');
});
```

CSS

```
    .imgvideo {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.playbutton {
  background: url(https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/vector-basic-tab-bar-icons/48/play_button-128.png) center center no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 74px;
  height: 74px;
  margin: -37px 0 0 -37px;
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: .6;
}

.ytvideo {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  /* pour anciens Chrome et Safari */
  background-size: cover;
  /* version standardisée */
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ytvideo iframe {
  border-style: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.ytvideo .seo {
  display: none;
}
```

I've googled "youtube play on click image" then found this: http://jsfiddle.net/onigetoc/81tztuk1/

Comment: I also added this code: .ytvideo:before {content: ' '; display: block; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 1; opacity: 0.59; background-color: #f1d2cd; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 50% 0; background-size: cover;} and I can not do anything with the movie. How do I disable opacity after starting a movie?

Comment: you can use a toggleClass on jQuery or change the opacity with CSS in jQuery